# Readings, tools and libraries for low-level, network related, softwares in C

Tags: c, networking, drivers, low-level, firmware

I'm going to graduate soon in electronics and tlc engineering and I have some decent OO programming experience with PHP and Java.
Now I would like to try starting a career as a C programmer.
I'm interested in C since this is, I think, the most suited language, without considering Assembly, to develop device drivers, firmwares and other low-level softwares in.
In particular I hope to be able to work on network related topics.
I want to work quite close to the hardware since I suppose this is the only way I'll be able to fruitfully spend my degree while at the same time finding gratification in being a programmer.
So I'd like to ask what you think I should read considering that I can already write something in C, nothing fancy though, and that I've read a couple of times the K&R.

If you know of any tools or libraries (like libevent and libev) that are de facto standards in the field of low-level, network related, C programming that would be nice to know as well.

Answer (score 3):

In no particular order:

- [Unix Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551)
- [The Standard C Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099)
- [Beginning Linux Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470147628)
- [Professional Linux Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471776130)
- [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)

Comment: The Stevens books have been the bible for network programming for a long time.

Comment: The Stevens book volume 1 is even 1024 pages long for that extra geek cred!

Answer (score 2):

Must read books:

- TCP/IP Illustrated, Stevens
- UNIX Network Programming, Stevens, et al

For system-level networking code (you expressed an interest in drivers, etc) see [OpenBSD sources](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/sys/net/) since it's tight, clean, and the standard networking APIs are based almost completely on BSD.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how low level you want to go. There is a small stack called [uIP](http://www.sics.se/~adam/uip/index.php/Main_Page)
 which is a good read, its well documented and has a few papers written about it. Its a lot closer to the hardware then any of linux socket/io programming since there is no kernel to get in the way.

You may want to also take a look at tcpdump, its a nice cli based sniffer, (written in c) so you can use it as well as take it apart!

Answer (score 1):

[Beej's guide to Network Programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/reference.html#books) is a good place to get started. If you want to go down the rabbit hole then as many others have recommended take a look at Unix Network Programming, volumes 1-2 by W. Richard Stevens.

Answer (score 0):

How about the libcurl source? Take a look [here](http://curl.haxx.se/devel.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've used this ["Linux I/O port programming mini-HOWTO"](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/IO-Port-Programming.html) a number of times. This is C code.

There are also a number of C code samples for [serial I/O](http://www.taltech.com/freesoftware/fs_sw.htm#completec).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly C specific but packet sniffers like Wireshark can be really useful for testing & debugging network related programs.